Marshal.CreateAggregatedObject()
I am trying to aggregate a .net comvisible object in another COM object. I have coded it as below. 'pUnkOuter' and 'fullAssemblyPath' are inputs to the method where the code below is (this code is in a .net assembly which is called from C++ code). The problem is the caller of this method in C++ is not able to QI on the returned  'innerUnknown'. The QI is not able to get the interfaces that the .NET object implements. Intellisense in C++ show the returned object as RCW object. So how to setup the code below so that C++ code gets the inner unknown and the QI on that succeeds?
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullAssemblyPath);

Type typeToLoad = assembly.GetType(className.ToString());

object netObject = typeToLoad.GetConstructor(new Type[] { 
  }).Invoke(new object[] { });

IntPtr innerUnknown = Marshal.CreateAggregatedObject(Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(pUnkOuter), netObject);

return innerUnknown;

